# How to match current month from timestamp field?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a field named `modified` which value is timestamp. i.e: `2015-11-10 07:42:56`

I want to match current month only, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE modified = 2015-11
```

I will replace `2015-11` by current month. But how can I compare only `yyyy-mm` part from this timestamp value?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Too many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...

Comment: I am using mysql database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `YEAR` and `MONTH`

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(modified) = '2015' AND MONTH(modified) = '11'`

Answer (score 0):

If the `modified` column is indexed, do something like below to get better performance:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE modified >= '2015-11-01' and modified < '2015-12-01'
```

Note: I'm not quite sure about these date literals. (Not a MySQL user.)